# How do I build an array based on data using two criteria (Array Formula [pref] or VBA)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-formula

I have the following example data:

[image: Example data table from Excel]

The first column is a list of names, the second column is the year those names belong to.

What I want to do is build a list of all unique (distinct) names from one year.
So for example in the year 2016 I want it to build a list like in the end result column, while in the year 2017 I want it to build a list with the unique names of that year.

Preferably I want it to be a (dynamic) named range so that the calculation only has to be performed once and so that I can use the `=INDEX(examplenamedrange, 1)` formula to call the names that I want to use.

If this is not possible in a dynamic named range then storing the array in VBA is also a possibility.

I’ve seen a few Excel formulas around the net that look at unique values in a list, but none that I could find with an extra criteria (in this case: Year).

Can anyone set me on the right path?

Comment: Can't you just copy the data into another column and remove duplicates?

Comment: Can you post some example data at all hard to post the array formula w/o the data to see.  This `=INDEX($A$3:$A$602,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$3:$B3,$A$3:$A$502),0))` for example, in B3:Bx gets the unique list from a3:a502.  You would need  `((MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$3:$B3,$A$3:$A$502))*(year($a$3:$A3)=2016))` or something similar.

Comment: Hey Mick, Nathan,
Preferably I don't want to copy the data into another tab, the original data in the tab is not to be mutated (the other data is still required for some other calculations)

The example data was provided as an image, basically it's only two columns so using A:A and B:B would work.

Would COUNTIFS work?

So something along the lines of (needs to be adjusted for 100% correctness): 

=INDEX($A$3:$A$602,MATCH(0,COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$500,2016,$A$3:$A$500,$A$2:$A3),0))

Comment: Check out my answer. It's VBA and you can modify it to use different columns if necessary.

Comment: I've tried so much and I can only achieve it using a helper column that you could hide... Is that okay?

Comment: Hey @Glitch_Doctor,
A helper column would not be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add another similar, but different method in there. You can use a UDF which returns an array. So paste the code into a code module and then use the following formula on the worksheet

```
=GetNamesInYear(names,dates,2016)
```

where `names` is your range of names, `dates` is your range of dates and `2016` is the year you are searching, either a number written in the formula or reference to a cell with the value `2016` is fine.

To return the full array you need to enter the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. To view all results, rather than just the first result, highlight that cell and the 5 below it (say), press <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

Alternatively you can access the array with any worksheet function that can deal with string arrays. For example:

```
=INDEX(GetNamesInYear(names,dates,2016),2)
```

returns the second item in the array

---

Here is the code

```
Function GetNamesInYear(names As Range, years As Range, year As Integer) As Variant
    Dim namesArr As Variant
    namesArr = names.Value2

    Dim yearsArr As Variant
    yearsArr = years.Value2

    Dim results As Long
    results = 0

    Dim resultArr As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    ReDim resultArr(0 To 0)
    For i = 1 To UBound(namesArr, 1)
        If Not InArray(resultArr, namesArr(i, 1)) And (yearsArr(i, 1) = year) Then
            ReDim Preserve resultArr(0 To results)
            resultArr(results) = namesArr(i, 1)
            results = results + 1
        End If
    Next i

    GetNamesInYear = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(resultArr)
End Function

Private Function InArray(arr As Variant, value As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = value Then
            InArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    InArray = False
End Function
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

**Update**
Names and dates inputs are now split out (separate ranges) as per comments from OP

Comment: Hey @CallumDA,
I tried your solution because it seemed like the most flexible one.
It definitely works but what I'm wondering is if there is a way to get it to keep working when additional columns are added between column A and column B?

Comment: Yes, I can amend it to take the two ranges (names and years) separately. Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Preferably yes, since it would help me understand how to code similarly in the future, as well as futureproofing the project I'm working on.

Comment: @FSDT, I've updated as per your request. I hope that helps. Please note if you are treating this as a guide there is no error checking (for example, it will throw `#VALUE` if the names and years ranges are different sizes) You might like to deal with that in the code - maybe something you can experiment with.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short VBA sub to achieve what you ask.

To set up a sub, press `Alt`+`F11` to open VBA editor, then `Insert`>`Module` and paste the following code. I have commented it to show what each section is doing. You could also set this up to run when the Year cell is changed, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you! To run it, press `F5` in the VBA editor or click the run button.

```
Sub uniqueInYear()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ActiveSheet

    Dim vcell As Range

    Dim namesString As String
    namesString = ""

    Dim namesList() As String

    ' Compile string with all names comma separated for given year
    For Each vcell In Range("A2:A" & sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

        ' check if name already captured for given year
        If InStr(namesString, vcell.Value) = 0 And vcell.Offset(0, 1).Value = sh.Range("E1").Value Then

            namesString = namesString & "," & vcell.Value

        End If

    Next vcell

    ' If empty then quit
    If namesString = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Remove leading comma
    namesString = Right(namesString, Len(namesString) - 1)

    ' Put names into array
    namesList = Split(namesString, ",")

    ' Write names to result column after clearing it
    sh.Range("E2:E" & sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1).Value = ""

    Dim nameVar As Variant
    For Each nameVar In namesList

        sh.Range("E" & sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = nameVar

    Next nameVar

    ' Named range - delete if it exists then create a-fresh
    On Error Resume Next
    sh.Parent.Names("UniqueNames").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    sh.Parent.Names.Add name:="UniqueNames", _
                        RefersTo:=sh.Range("E2", sh.Range("E" &     sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1).End(xlUp))

End Sub
```

Outcome:

[image]

Comment: Hey Wolfie, 
Thank you for the help, seems appropriate for my use case so I'll give it a go if the array formula doesn't turn out the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
Sub Names()
    Dim x, Years, Counted, ColumnCount, j, lColumn
    Dim Names(), FoundNames()
    Years = Range("B1").Value
    Counted = 0
    ColumnCount = 2
    ReDim Names(Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row)
    ReDim FoundNames(LBound(Names) To UBound(Names))
    lColumn = Cells(1, Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Column
    For Each c In Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
        If Years <> Range("B" & c.row).Value Then
            For i = LBound(Names) To UBound(Names)
                If Names(i) <> "" Then
                    j = j + 1
                    FoundNames(j - 1) = Names(i)
                End If
            Next i
            ReDim Preserve FoundNames(LBound(Names) To j - 1)
            Cells(1, lColumn + ColumnCount).Value = Years
            For i = LBound(FoundNames) To UBound(FoundNames)
                Cells(i + 2, lColumn + ColumnCount).Value = FoundNames(i)
            Next
            ColumnCount = ColumnCount + 1
            Years = Range("B" & c.row).Value
            Counted = 0
            ReDim Names(Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row)
            ReDim FoundNames(LBound(Names) To UBound(Names))
        End If

        If InStr(Join(Names, ","), c.Value) < 1 Then
            Names(Counted) = c.Value
            Counted = Counted + 1
        End If
    Next c
    j = 0
    For i = LBound(Names) To UBound(Names)
        If Names(i) <> "" Then
            j = j + 1
            FoundNames(j - 1) = Names(i)
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve FoundNames(LBound(Names) To j - 1)
    Cells(1, lColumn + ColumnCount).Value = Years
    For i = LBound(FoundNames) To UBound(FoundNames)
        Cells(i + 2, lColumn + ColumnCount).Value = FoundNames(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

The results look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Array formula can work here:

`=INDEX($A$1:$A$15, N(IF({1}, MODE.MULT(IF(($B$1:$B$15=2016)*(ROW($A$1:$A$15)=MATCH($A$1:$A$15, $A$1:$A$15, 0)), (ROW($A$1:$A$15)) * {1,1})))))`

Define your named range as dynaRange_2016, and see it's use in the two images

[image]:

[image]

You could name a range for each year instead, and then define yet another name for the uniques range. This is more versatile:

define Named range_2017 as `=INDEX(Sheet5!$A:$A, MATCH(2017,Sheet5!$B:$B, 0)):INDEX(Sheet5!$A:$A, MATCH(2017,Sheet5!$B:$B, 1))`

Then define another named range uniques_2017 as`=INDEX(Sheet5!range_2017, N(IF({1}, MODE.MULT(IF(ROW(Sheet5!range_2017)-MATCH(2017, Sheet5!$B:$B, 0)+1=MATCH(Sheet5!range_2017, Sheet5!range_2017, 0), (ROW(Sheet5!range_2017)-MATCH(2017,  Sheet5!$B:$B, 0)+1) * {1,1})))))`

In your sheet, you can call as INDEX(uniques_2017, 3) for example. Do the same for all years that you expect to occur.

Comment: Hey @MacroMarc,
I tried to use your formula today and just replaced the A and B columns in the formula with the columns in my own file, unfortunately all the formules either give a #N/A, a #REF or #VALUE error.

I do have to mention that in the final file there are a few columns inbetween where row A and row B are supposed to be.

After evaluating the formula it seems the error occurs at the second argument of the match formula, do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: After trying a few things it seems that the array formula only works if you know the exact length of the list, so in your example putting A1:A16 or B1:B16 seems to already cause the formula to fail, Is there a workaround for this, perhaps by using countif?

Comment: Can you post the EXACT formula you have used in my style? Also what assumptions can we make about the data structure? Blanks etc